# Access navigation control: load same form in Add mode or Edit mode

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to play a bit with a Navigation form in Access 2010.
To simplify, I would like to have 2 buttons, 1 to load a subform in *Data Entry mode*, the other one to load the **SAME subForm** in *Edit mode* (but with a filter).

The first idea I had is to check from the Open event of the subform which button was clicked in the Navigation form and set the sub form properties (`DataEntry`, `AllowEdits`) accordingly.

- Is that the right way to achieve my goal ?
- How can I find which NavigationButton is active in the Navigation form, from the subform ?

I played with the properties, examined the objects in debug mode but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer....In the Navigation form, I removed the form name from the navigation button and I added this code:

```
Private Sub NavigationButton7_Click()
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "Trades", "Menu.NavigationSubForm"
    With NavigationSubform.Form
        .AllowAdditions = True
        .DataEntry = True
    End With
End Sub
```